# Using Hazelcast to replace shared memory structures data

Tags: c++, hazelcast

I am completely new to using Hazelcast. Currently I am maintaining a large set of structures data in shared memory which I access through the shared memory key. The memory for the predefined data element structures (say, some 20000+) is initially created in Shared memory and later used by applications on the same system using the shared memory key.

Whether Hazelcast provides any built-in APIs or data structures to facilitate access and maintain this data more efficiently than using my current shared memory structures? Please note that I am trying to use the C++ version of the Hazelcast library for the program which I will run on the single system where all other applications access the shared memory data.

Any code fragment to maintain the data locally in the above scenario will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast is a clustered environment, it is not designed as a single node runtime. Even though you could most probably achieve what you want the performance will be way worse than shared memory and you're not really using it in a common Hazelcast use case.